# Programmatically Start Clock of Specific Heading? (Org-Mode)

Tags: org-mode

I'm aware of `C-c C-x C-i (org-clock-in)` which starts the clock on the current heading.

**Question:** Is there a way to *programmatically* target a specific heading with this command? That is, if I have

```
* Task A
** Task B
```

Is there a way for me to execute a command which starts the clock for `Task B` no matter where I am?

**EDIT:** I have since discovered `helm-org-agenda-files-headings`, when -- when called -- allows you to search and jump to any heading across your agenda files. This is nearly perfect except you can't programmatically go to the first match with something like `(helm-org-agenda-files-headings "Task A/Task B")` You can only `(helm-org-agenda-files-headings)` with no arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Org does seem to lack programmatic interfaces for many aspects like this.  I would recommend using heading ID's for the application you describe as it virtually eliminates any ambiguity in finding your desired heading.  Be sure your desired heading has an ID (you can create it by calling `org-id-get-create` with your point on the heading) like the following:

```
* Task A
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       22cba7a6-137d-4f06-8547-47a8bf1eb19e
:END:
** Task B
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       65d813d9-e513-482f-bb65-6430d1027666
:END:
```

You can then programmatically start the clock using a function like the following:

```
(defun my/start-heading-clock (id file)
  "Start clock programmatically for heading with ID in FILE."
  (require 'org-id)
  (if-let (marker (org-id-find-id-in-file id file t))
      (save-current-buffer
        (save-excursion
          (set-buffer (marker-buffer marker))
          (goto-char (marker-position marker))
          (org-clock-in)))
    (warn "Clock not started (Could not find ID '%s' in file '%s')" id file)))

(my/start-heading-clock "65d813d9-e513-482f-bb65-6430d1027666" "~/your-task-file.org")
```

Note that there are other ways of locating the heading.  To find a heading using the content of the heading itself you could use:

```
(find-file "your-task-file.org")
(org-find-exact-headline-in-buffer "Task B" (current-buffer))
```

(FWIW there is also `org-find-exact-heading-in-directory`)

I would recommend something like `org-id-find` as org can keep track of the locations of ID's in all agenda files (with `org-id-track-globally`).  Using that, you only need to specify the heading ID:

```
(org-id-find "65d813d9-e513-482f-bb65-6430d1027666" t)
```

The only downside to using this strategy is that org can take a long time updating its ID locations index.  I hope this helps!

Comment: Instead of searching a specific `file`, is there a way to make it default to all files in current agenda list?

Comment: @George  Yup.  You should be able to just replace the `(org-id-find-id-in-file id file t)` instruction with `(org-id-find id t)`.