# org-id-find-id-in-file function definition is void?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

After re-arranging my spacemacs configuration file, I'm now getting

```
Symbol's function definition is void: org-id-find-id-in-file
```

After running a custom function that makes use of this symbol.

I cannot pin down what change is causing this; moreover, this looks like a stock symbol so it's bothering that it's definition can't be found.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like my function to [Programmatically Start Clock of Specific Heading](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/36325/2731) is causing some problems for you ;-)  It looks like you may need to explicitly include `org-id` (in case none of the autoloaded functions in `org-id.el` have been used by the time you invoke `my/start-heading-clock`).

Add `(require 'org-id)` to the body of `my/start-heading-clock`.  I'll update that answer accordingly.

Comment: I use your function several times per day, and this solves the issue. Thanks for editing it.

Comment: @George Fantastic to hear!  I'm glad it's been useful :-)